# Extract part of a variable

Tags: string, batch-file, variables, cmd

I'm trying to extract the name of the file that is on loop as a string. to organize many software outputs in different folders, named by the current process file.

So far i got this, but i can't get the string on the variable:

```
set DirecoryT=%%G
FOR /R D:\LiDAR_Data\LiDAR_DATA_EBA\ %%G in (*.laz) do (
    echo Directory %DirecoryT%
    set File=%DirecoryT:~29,9%
    echo Processing file %File%
pause
)
pause
```

Comment: does it make sense to assign `%%G` to a variable, before `%%G` even exists? (Hint; no). You should also learn about [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082).

Comment: I bet if you read the very last section of the help file for the `FOR` command you will be amazed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a go at this:

```
@echo off
for /R "D:\LiDAR_Data\LiDAR_DATA_EBA\" %%G in (*.laz) do (
   echo File Extension only: "%%~xG"
   echo FileName with Extension: "%%~nxG"
   echo FileName without Extension: "%%~nG"
   echo Full path and name: "%%G"
   echo Directory to file only: "%%~pG"
   echo Drive and directory is: "%%~dpG"
 )
 pause
```

Notice how we get the various parts of the string. For more on variable handling, simply run `for /?` from command line and read the help.

So a little closer to what you actually want, based on your attempt.

```
@echo off
for /R "D:\LiDAR_Data\LiDAR_DATA_EBA\" %%G in (*.laz) do (
   echo FileName "%%~nxG"
   echo Directory "%%~dpG"
   echo Processing file "%%~nxG"
 )
 pause
```

**EDIT**

As per your last comment to see only the last folder where the file exists:

```
@echo off
for /R "D:\LiDAR_Data\LiDAR_DATA_EBA\" %%G in (*.laz) do (
   echo FileName "%%~nxG"
   echo Directory "%%~dpG"
   echo Processing file "%%~nxG"
  for %%i in ("%%~dpG\.") do echo Last Folder "%%~nxi"
 )
pause
```

Comment: And how can I echo the folder that contains the file?
Exemple: on C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\file.txt i wanna get only the "folder4" string.

Comment: @ViníciusPeripato see the edited code at the bottom of answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
for %%a in ("%pathToFile%") do set "newvariable=%%~na"
```

Comment: This code looks nothing like their existing code. Nor will it do the same thing especially since we do not know what is assigned to the %pathToFile% variable.

Comment: No, this is completely wrong. `%pathtoFile%` where is that? Why run a script if you are going to specify exact path to the file? This is not even close to what the OP asked.